# How are pages on different tabs notified when logging out from Google account?

Tags: google-account, firefox

When I logout in my browser (Firefox) from Google account, I can see that some pages in other tabs (not all belong to Google ecosystem) are refreshed and I guess that some logout notification was delivered by something to them. How does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to depend on how each application has implemented Google's API for user authentication. Most likely there's some Websocket or AJAX calls going on in the background polling Google to see if you're logged on. When it finds that you're not the calling app changes your status.

Comment: It's more likely that the application would be polling for something else such as updates of actual displayed information, possibly using a websocket in some scenarios. The log-off might be an error message passed since the user is no longer authenticated.

Comment: Ah, yes. Websockets are probably more likely nowadays. Thanks @hex. I'll update my answer.